# Can Apache Cordova be used in hybrid with Objective-C?

Tags: ios, cordova

Is Apache Cordova meant to replace native languages for desired runtime capabilities or is it meant to be used in addition with them? For example if my iOS app written in Objective-C named iTime can run a stop watch using an `NSTimer` could I then write some code in `Cordova` to initiate say the cordova iOS camera plugin abilities within the existing iTime app? Or can one only use Cordova with  cordova code. My question is: can Apache Cordova be used in hybrid with Objective-C or only in its stead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want, you can create apps with just native code ( full native), you can create them just using html, css and javascript ( full cordova), and you can mix both of them embedding the cordova webview into your native project (real hybrid)

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html

Answer (score 1):

Apache cordova is a framework that can help in developing hybrid apps..
Yes, to avoid the implementation on native code,apps are developed in hybrid.But that doesn't mean the the native code is completely ignored or removed...Apache binds the way that for the native specific code to be included as plugin and on installation these code is added to the application structure and get executed along with the capability of web based languages that can do functions capable on the native webkit framework

As the example says you have an native application and to add a feature using cordova..The question will be, since it is a common feature available why go for hybrid code from there ?...after all what cordova going to do is to add boiler plate code available for such function to be added to the code and interconnect with hybrid code.

Hybrid is a whole new way to develop from scratch so that the multiplatform can support the same code base.But the native implementation for some features are not an avoidable and hence they will be or they must be using the native code to run.

Plugins are the major feature supporter for these apps and when developing a plugin you are actually writing native code and provide provision to call from hybrid side into native execute the requirement and go back to [callback] JS code.

How it works

Native Web kit [UIWebview]=> display/Run JS with help of cordova as an application
If u need a feature that is not capable via native webkit[native browser]/ that cannot be called by js[hybrid] ===Cordova provide integral logic to call the native code as plugin===>Call the native code =>Execute =>give the run control back to hybrid.

This is how it works.Hope you understand

Go through the docs ...See some samples...Of Course try coding to get a better understanding.

**Nobody wants hybrid code in native apps...its always Native code in hybrid apps.**

Btw: I worked in 3 environments : iOS ,Android and cordova